# Z value of ECDSA

Tags: transactions

I am trying to validate an ethereum tx using ECDSA.

R(x, y) = uG + vQ
where u= zs^-1, v = rs^-1, Q= Public key

For following tx 0x8b69a0ca303305a92d8d028704d65e4942b7ccc9a99917c8c9e940c9d57a9662 from https://medium.com/@codetractio/inside-an-ethereum-transaction-fa94ffca912f.
what would be the z value and how its computed.

Answer (score 1):

I think

- z is the hash of the message.
- z=hash(m)

or precisely z is the leftmost bits of the resulting hash(m),
checkout https://www.coindesk.com/math-behind-bitcoin/
and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Correctness_of_the_algorithm